# Decimal to Hex help understanding

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Dec2Hex {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a decimal number:  ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        
        String hex = "";
        
        while (decimal != 0) {
            int hexValue = decimal % 16;
            char hexDigit = (0 <= hexValue && hexValue <= 9)?
               (char)(hexValue + '0'):  (char)(hexValue - 10 + 'A');
               
               hex = hexDigit + hex;
               decimal = decimal/16;
               
        }
        System.out.println("The hex number is  " + hex);
    }
}
```

This is an example in my book.  I understand most of it but can't quite grasp a few parts.  The example uses 1234 as the decimal entered.

1. The remainder of 1234/16 is 2 so hexValue is 2.  Therefore hexDigit is 2 + '0'.  But hexDigit is a character so what is the meaning of combining or adding 2 and '0'?
2. The final answer is 4D2.  Where in the code did we ever provide instruction for any letter other than 'A'?  How did it come up with a 'D'?

Thank you!

Comment: 2 is added to character `'0'` to get character value `'2'` to be added to the hex string. Similarly  hex digits for 10..15 are A..F, thus appropriate char is calculated as mentioned in the code.

Comment: 2) Same way you got 1 through 9 even though you literally added `'0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every char has a value number between 0 to 256, each of these numbers encode a printable sign.

For example the value of '0' is 48, and the value of 'A' is 65.

So when adding a constant offset to a character it's like going to that offset in that encoding.

For example '0' + 5 is '5', or 'A' + 3 is 'D'.

So as for your questions:

1. '0' + 2 is '2', i.e. the printable character of 2.
2. In the code hexValue  had the value of 13, so hexDigit got the value (hexValue - 10 + 'A'), which is (hexValue - 10 + 'A') = 13 - 10 + 'A' = 'A' + 3 = 'D'.

Answer (score 2):

I understand now that the second part of the condition is takin a number like "13", subtracting 10 and adding that to 'A'.  3 + 'A' is 'D' in unicode.

I still do not understand adding the '0' to the first part of the condition. Couldn't we just say (char)(hexValue)?  Why add '0'?

Thanks!

Comment: "Couldn't we just say (char)(hexValue)? Why add '0'?"  If you convert 2 to char, you get a [special character](http://www.asciitable.com/), not the character '2'.  The value '0' is really 48, so we add hexValue to 48 and that gets converted to the corresponding digit 0 to 9.

Comment: Remember that the output of the function is a string value. The individual characters have to be translated to the characters represented by the hex digits which are integer values between 0 and 15.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The remainder of 1234/16 is 2 so hexValue is 2. Therefore hexDigit is 2 + '0'. But hexDigit is a character so what is the meaning of combining or adding 2 and '0'?

The value `2` is an integer value, however the variable type is `char`. No problem in assigning such a value to a `char` variable, however this would result in the `0x02` character/byte, which is a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), not a visible character to display. The digits in the ASCII table to display begins at `0x30` (which is the digit `'0'`). To get the character value to save in the `char` variable you add your calculated value `2` with the offset `0x30`. To make this calculation easier you use the expression `'0'`. This is the exact value of `0x30` (or `48` in decimal).

> 2. The final answer is 4D2. Where in the code did we ever provide instruction for any letter other than 'A'? How did it come up with a 'D'?

The calculation is as follow:

1. `1234` divided by `16` is `77` with a remainder of `2`.
2. `77` divided by `16` is `4` with a remainder of `13` (which is `D`).
3. `4` divided by `16` is `0` with a remainder of `4`.

This results in `4D2`. To verify:

```
4*16*16 + 13*16 + 2 = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2 + '0' = 2 + 48 = 50
(char)50 = '2'
```

Note that

```
'0' = 48
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
...
'9' = 57
```

Check [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to learn more about ASCII values.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((char) 50);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is used for char type, so characters can be represented by decimal values. For example:

- '0' in decimal 48
- '1' in decimal 49
- '2' in decimal 50
- ...
- '9' in decimal 57
- 'A' in decimal 65
- 'B' in decimal 66
- 'C' in decimal 67
- 'D' in decimal 68
- ...
- 'Z' in decimal 90
- 'a' in decimal 97
- 'b' in decimal 98
- ...
- 'z' in decimal 122

Having that in mind your here are the answers to your questions:

We focus on the line

```
char hexDigit = (0 <= hexValue && hexValue <= 9)?
           (char)(hexValue + '0'):  (char)(hexValue - 10 + 'A');
```

> 1. The remainder of 1234/16 is 2 so hexValue is 2. Therefore hexDigit is
>    2 + '0'. But hexDigit is a character so what is the meaning of
>    combining or adding 2 and '0'?

For this question the part of interest is

```
(char)(hexValue + '0')
```

The value **hexValue** is 2, so **hexValue + '0'** is 50, because in ascii table '0' has decimal value 48. Than value of 50 is casted to char, which by ascii table is '2'.

> 2. The final answer is 4D2. Where in the code did we ever provide
>    instruction for any letter other than 'A'? How did it come up with a
>    'D'?

For this question the part of interest is

```
(char)(hexValue - 10 + 'A')
```

The value **hexValue** is 13. By asci table 'A' has value of 65 and 'D' has value of 68. So hexValue - 10 is 3 and when we sum 3 and 'A' we get 68. Finally we do cast to char and get 'D'.

You can easyly test the answers by executing this piece of code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Decimal value: "+(2+'0')+"   Char value:" +(char)(2+'0'));
    System.out.println("Decimal value: "+(3 + 'A')+"   Char value: "+ (char)(3+'A'));
}
```

}
Regards